How to add a default image to django ImageField with Amazon S3 for file storage?
I made a custom user model that contains an imagefield for the avatar:
class User(AbstractUser):
    avi_pic = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='avi/', default='avi/default_avi.jpg')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

I want to have a default avi for all new users so I added the image to my AWS3 bucket and added the path to the model field. The path to that image in my S3 bucket is:
mybucket/media/avi/default_avi.png
To create the user i have an APIView:
class CreateUser(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = UserRegisterSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            user = serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

^ when registering new user only a username is submitted.
and model serializer:
class UserRegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username')

    def validate_username(self, value):
        if User.objects.filter(username=value).exists():
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Username is already taken.")
        allowed_characters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_-.'
        if any(char not in allowed_characters for char in value):
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Invalid characters in username.")
        return value

My problem is that when i create a new account the user doesn't get the default image. I have configured my settings like this:
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'https://MYBUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com/media'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.environ['AWS_S3_REGION_NAME']
AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_NAME = os.environ['AWS_S3_SIGNATURE_NAME']
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = os.environ['AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE']
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = os.environ['AWS_DEFAULT_ACL']
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = os.environ['AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH']
AWS_S3_VERIFY = os.environ['AWS_S3_VERIFY']

and I included this to my projects main urls.py:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Is there something i'm missing or configuring wrong?
Also when i log in to the Django admin panel and go to a user, it says "no file chosen" next to the avi image field.
